# "Transposing" a table to multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | a | b | c | d | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| f | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| g | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| h | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| i | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| j | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| a | f | 1 |
| a | g | 3 |
| a | h | 3 |
| a | i | 2 |
| a | j | 2 |
| b | f | 3 |
| b | g | 1 |
| b | h | 3 |
| b | i | 2 |
| b | j | 1 |
| c | f | 3 |
| c | g | 3 |
| c | h | 1 |
| c | i | 3 |
| c | j | 3 |
| d | f | 2 |
| d | g | 2 |
| d | h | 3 |
| d | i | 1 |
| d | j | 2 |
| e | f | 2 |
| e | g | 1 |
| e | h | 3 |
| e | i | 2 |
| e | j | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

I'm using this macro:

```
   Sub ColumnCopy()

Sheets("test").Cells.Clear

Dim tRow As Long
Dim source As String
Dim target As String

    source = "test1"       'Set your source sheet here
    target = "test"       'Set the Target sheet name

    'tRow = 2                'Define the start row of the target sheet

    'Get Last Row and Column
    lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Sheets(source).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    tRow = 2
    colBase = 2
    Do While colBase < lastCol
        For iRow = 2 To lastRow

            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 1) = Sheets(source).Cells(1, colBase)
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 2) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, 1)
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 3) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, colBase)

            tRow = tRow + 1
        Next iRow
        colBase = colBase + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

But i'm getting result missing the "column e":

```
+---+---+---+
| a | f | 1 |
| a | g | 3 |
| a | h | 3 |
| a | i | 2 |
| a | j | 2 |
| b | f | 3 |
| b | g | 1 |
| b | h | 3 |
| b | i | 2 |
| b | j | 1 |
| c | f | 3 |
| c | g | 3 |
| c | h | 1 |
| c | i | 3 |
| c | j | 3 |
| d | f | 2 |
| d | g | 2 |
| d | h | 3 |
| d | i | 1 |
| d | j | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

I can't find what's causing this issue. I'm really new to excel macro.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this: `Do While colBase < lastCol` to this:

```
Do While colBase <= lastCol
```